# Unable to connect to Backendless API Server

Tags: backendless

When I am trying to login to my account I having problem in backendless site and also through my application.

It says
"Unable to connect to Backendless API Server. Please contact your System Administrator"

Also not able to log this problem with support team, as they need login and its giving error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're experiencing a service outage. We're providing updates on it in our [Slack channel](http://slack.backendless.com).

Comment: thanks @Mark. Before 20 min it solved and now I can see my application data.